# Backgroundworker Progressbar freezes

Tags: vb.net

So I've finally got this to *almost* work but now every few times I test the process the form and the progressbar freeze. I'm also sure there are much more efficient ways of doing this so any constructive criticism would be greatly appreciated.

This is the coding for one page of a program that allows the user to click one button to download and install one application and then press the next button to download and install a different application:

```
Imports System.Net.WebRequestMethods
Public Class Software

'Open link in external browser
Public Sub HandleRequestNavigate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RequestNavigateEventArgs)
    Process.Start(New ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri))
    e.Handled = True
End Sub

'Declarations
Shared progressamc As New Progress
Shared progresscti As New ProgressCTI
WithEvents startcti As New Process
WithEvents startamc As New Process
WithEvents startsfstb As New Process
WithEvents amcworker As New ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
WithEvents ctiworker As New ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
Dim ProgressBarAMC As Object = Progress.ProgressBar1
Dim blprgrsAMC As Object = Progress.blprgrs
Dim ProgressBarCTI As Object = progresscti.ProgressBar1
Dim blprgrsCTI As Object = progresscti.blprgrs


'FTP Values
Const host As String = "ftp://10.167.16.80/"
Const username As String = "anonymous"
Const password As String = ""
'AMC File Put/Get
Const localfileamc As String = "C:\AMC.exe"
Const Remotefileamc As String = "Bin/AMC.exe"
'CTI File Put/Get
Const localfilecti As String = "C:\CTI.exe"
Const Remotefilecti As String = "Bin/CTI.exe"

'On Init
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    amcworker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    amcworker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    ctiworker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    ctiworker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
End Sub

'Install AMC Button
Private Sub ButtonAMC(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim butt1 As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    butt1.IsEnabled = False
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(New Action(AddressOf progressamc_Show))
    AddHandler Progress.Cancel_Click, AddressOf myProcessamc_Exited
    amcworker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

'Open Dialog
Private Sub progressamc_Show()
    Try
        progressamc.ShowDialog()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred during the process:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please close the application and try again." _
                & vbCrLf & "If you continue to encounter this error please Email")
    End Try
End Sub

'FTP - Download
Private Sub ftpseshamc_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles amcworker.DoWork
    Dim URI As String = host & Remotefileamc
    Dim FTP As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = CType(System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(URI), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
    'Set the credentials
    FTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password)
    'FTP Options
    FTP.KeepAlive = False
    FTP.UseBinary = True
    'Define the action as Download
    FTP.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
    'Get the response to the Ftp request and the associated stream
    Try
        Dim response As System.Net.FtpWebResponse = CType(FTP.GetResponse, System.Net.FtpWebResponse)
        Dim Length As Long = response.ContentLength
        Dim StopWatch As New Stopwatch
        Dim CurrentSpeed As Double = Nothing
        Using responseStream As IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream
            'loop to read & write to file
            Using fs As New IO.FileStream(localfileamc, IO.FileMode.Create)
                Dim buffer(2047) As Byte
                Dim read As Integer = 0
                Dim count As Integer
                Do
                    If amcworker.CancellationPending = True Then
                        e.Cancel = True
                        Return
                    End If
                    StopWatch.Start()
                    amcworker.ReportProgress(CShort(count / Length * 100 + 0.5))
                    read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, read)
                    count += read
                Loop Until read = 0
                StopWatch.Stop()
                responseStream.Close()
                fs.Flush()
                fs.Close()
            End Using
            responseStream.Close()
        End Using
        response.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred during the process:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please close the application and try again." _
                        & vbCrLf & "If you continue to encounter this error please Email")
        myProcessamc_Exited()
    End Try
    Installamc()
End Sub

'Starts the installation
Sub Installamc()
    startamc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\AMC.exe"
    startamc.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    Try
        startamc.Start()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Dispatcher.Invoke(New Action(AddressOf Progressamc_Hide))
End Sub
'Hide Dialog during install
Private Sub Progressamc_Hide()
    progressamc.Hide()
End Sub

'Report progress 
Private Sub amcworker_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles amcworker.ProgressChanged
    ProgressBarAMC.value = e.ProgressPercentage
    blprgrsAMC.Content = "Downloading: " & e.ProgressPercentage & "%"
End Sub

End Class
```

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I've made the following edit to the code but I'm not entirely sure it's doing what I think it's doing. Basically what I intended is for the ReportProgress to only run once every 2047 bytes read.

```
'Get the response to the Ftp request and the associated stream
    Try
        Dim response As System.Net.FtpWebResponse = CType(FTP.GetResponse, System.Net.FtpWebResponse)
        Dim Length As Long = response.ContentLength
        Dim StopWatch As New Stopwatch
        Dim CurrentSpeed As Double = Nothing
        Using responseStream As IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream
            'loop to read & write to file
            Using fs As New IO.FileStream(localfileamc, IO.FileMode.Create)
                Dim buffer(2047) As Byte
                Dim read As Integer = 0
                Dim count As Integer
                Dim chunk As Integer = Int(2047 / Length)
                Dim cycle As Integer = chunk = count
                Do
                    If amcworker.CancellationPending = True Then
                        e.Cancel = True
                        Return
                    End If
                    StopWatch.Start()
                    If cycle = True Then
                        amcworker.ReportProgress(CShort(count / Length * 100 + 0.5))
                    Else
                        End
                    End If
                    read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, read)
                    count += read
                Loop Until read = 0
                StopWatch.Stop()
                responseStream.Close()
                fs.Flush()
                fs.Close()
            End Using
            responseStream.Close()
        End Using
        response.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred during the process:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please close the application and try again." _
                        & vbCrLf & "If you continue to encounter this error please Email")
        myProcessamc_Exited()
    End Try
```

Comment: That is way too much code. Can you trim it down to a minimal example of your problem?

Comment: You are calling ReportProgress too often, pummeling the UI thread with updates.  It can't keep up.

Comment: Should it be placed elsewhere or is there a way I can put a timer on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't scrutinize the code carefully, but I don't see why you're using stopwatch, so I took out the references. I'm not sure what starting it multiple times inside the loop and ending it outside would do anyway.

The use of the word END in the second example will comletely end your app! Pretty sure that's what you want there.

Try this modification of your first code. The key is only updating if change is >= 5%:

```
       Using fs As New IO.FileStream(localfileamc, IO.FileMode.Create)
            Dim buffer(2047) As Byte
            Dim read As Integer = 0
            Dim count As Integer
            dim LastPct as Short = -5
            dim Pct as Short = 0 
            Do
                If amcworker.CancellationPending = True Then
                    e.Cancel = True
                    Return
                End If
                Pct = CShort(count / Length * 100 + 0.5)
                if Pct>= (LastPct + 5)
                    amcworker.ReportProgress(Pct)
                    LastPCT= Pct
                EndIf
                read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                fs.Write(buffer, 0, read)
                count += read
            Loop Until read = 0
            amcworker.ReportProgress(100)
            responseStream.Close()
            fs.Flush()
            fs.Close()
        End Using
```